# Where should I connect ground wire since no ground panel in the breaker box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am trying to install a 240v outlet. When I open the breaker box, I didn't find the grounding bar. I read some post. One post mentioned people need not to do that since I am using `(Metal Clad) Armorlite Cable` which already grounds to the metal box. Another post mentioned we have to connect the ground wire since it is there. I can drill a hole and screw the wire in the breaker box. Sounds like I should do as the second post? I am little confused whether should we connect the ground wire to the neutral bar. I suppose I should not? But actually, the neutral bar is connected to the metal box.

My second question is that I am installing a 240V/20A outlet which doesn't need neutral wire, only two hot wires and one ground wire. In this case, I just need to cut the neutral wire at the outlet end, or should I leave it alone? Should I connect it to the neutral bar in the breaker box? I guess yes, even though it isn't used?

Update: The wire I am using is `Solid CU BX/AC (AL Armored Cable)` https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-12-3-x-25-ft-Solid-CU-BX-AC-AL-Armored-Cable-Armorlite-Cable-61023221/202935702

I already installed the breaker and the hot wire. Will connect the neutral wire. So should I connect the ground wire to the neutral wire bar?
[image]
[image: connect to the breaker]
[image: detail]

Comment: There seems to be a lot of corrosion/rust on the neutral bus.  Rust can reduced electrical connection.  Might be something to have check out.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a sub panel so the neutral and ground bus bars do not have to be isolated. You have a green wire and a bare copper wire attached to the third bus bar in. That would be where your grounds would go. I can't tell from the picture if that bar is tied to the neutral. Metal clad cable needs a standard ground wire since the armor isn't part of the grounding. Armored cable has a thin grounding strip. Include a picture of the cable you're using in your post. Ground wires, if there, need to be connected.

Use a double pole breaker or two singles with handle ties.

Do not cut the neutral on the outlet side. You might need it some day. Just put a wire nut on it. You can leave it connected in the panel.

Comment: Thank you, @JACK. I just updated the new picture how I installed the breaker and the metal clad cable. So you are saying that it is ok to connect the neutral wire and the ground wire in the same bar? Forgive me, I didn't find the bar copper wire. Only see the green wire.  I will go downstairs to check again.

Comment: I just took a look in detail. There are three bus bar. The first one has many neutral wire connect. The third one (from left to right) has one wire connected but is still a neutral wire. What surprise me that the second bar has a hard connection to the box and are connected with the first bar and third bar. So it means the neutral wires are all connected to the box as well which means the ground wire and the neutral wire are connected. Did I miss something?

Comment: I think that is what you mentioned. In main panel, they are connected together. Since there isn't specific ground bus,  the ground wire can be connected to the box or one of the three neutral buses. Connect the bare copper wire to the neutral bus sounds weird.

Comment: @JuanHoo I thought the wire right above the green wire was an oxidized bare copper wire. In main panels, the neutrals and grounds can be connected together and to the panel box.  Use a separate holes for your neutral and ground wires. Connecting a bare copper ground to a neutral bus is OK in a main panel.  Turn your main breaker off and carefully clean up the panel.